# django validate and convert any image to jpeg then save

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have image field type file in model ...i want check user uploaded file is image or not if its image i want convert it to "jpeg" format for reduce size  and security purposes.. how can i do that ?

related view:

```
class StoreCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsSuperUserOrAdmin]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file_serial = ProductSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            if file_serial.is_valid():
                file_serial.save(author_id=request.user.id)
```

model:

```
def validate_image(image):
    if not image.is_image():
        raise ValidationError('File should be image.')

    file_size = image.file.size
    limit_kb = 200
    if file_size > limit_kb * 1024:
        raise ValidationError("Max size of file is {} KB".format(limit_kb))

# save the uploaded file in user directory
def upload_to_custom_p(instance, filename):
    name = instance.title
    user_id = str(instance.author.id)
    filename = filename.lower()
    return 'Product/img/user_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(user_id, name, filename)


class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    full_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_custom_p, null=True, blank=True,validators=[validate_image])
```

custom_path:

```
# save the uploaded file in user directory
def upload_to_custom_p(instance, filename):
    name = instance.title
    user_id = str(instance.author.id)
    filename = filename.lower()
    return 'Product/img/user_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(user_id, name, filename)
```

‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌

error log:

```
(uenv) [deb@arch academy]$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

/upload/upload/aa.mp4
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 22, 2018 - 15:52:01
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'academy.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.1.1 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-07-22 15:52:01,540 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2018-07-22 15:52:01,541 - INFO - server - Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2018-07-22 15:52:01,543 - INFO - server - Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/store/view/make/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 940, in create
    instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/academy/api/v1/store/models.py", line 42, in save
    image.save(image_io, format='JPEG')
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1950, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 762, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 496, in _save
    fp.write(d)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/academy/api/v1/store/views.py", line 269, in post
    file_serial.save(author_id=request.user.id)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 957, in create
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Product.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Product.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ProductSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 940, in create
    instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/academy/api/v1/store/models.py", line 42, in save
    image.save(image_io, format='JPEG')
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1950, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 762, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 496, in _save
    fp.write(d)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

[2018/07/22 15:52:32] HTTP POST /api/v1/store/view/make/ 500 [0.42, 127.0.0.1:52918]
```

Comment: If you just want to upload an image, You must be using `ImageField`, It auto validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

Comment: thnaks how can i convert image before save? i want convert any format of image to jpeg before save?

Comment: Check my answer, Let me know about any issues, I have not tested the code.

Comment: where should i use def save ?

Comment: Inside `Product` Model

Comment: I just checked the code in my local and it is working,
upgrade the pillow version to the latest if it is not Also, I updated my answer for PNG images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's recommended using `ImageField`, If you just want to upload an
>   image, It auto validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

Override save method of `Product` model and use `Image` class of `PIL` package to convert it to `JPEG`

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


class Product(models.Model):
   # attribute lies here
   ...

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.image:
         filename = "%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0]

         image = Image.open(self.image)
         # for PNG images discarding the alpha channel and fill it with some color
         if image.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
            background = Image.new(image.mode[:-1], image.size, '#fff')
            background.paste(image, image.split()[-1])
            image = background
         image_io = BytesIO()
         image.save(image_io, format='JPEG', quality=100)

         # change the image field value to be the newly modified image value
         self.image.save(filename, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()), save=False)

      super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it give me error that say : 

TypeError at /api/v1/store/view/make/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Product.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Product.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ProductSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohammadreza/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 477, in _save

Comment: if i make read_only 'image' it  will fix bud image will not save

Comment: update the code in question, where you are creating Product, which line of code raising this error

Comment: is this `file_serial.save(author_id=request.user.id)` line raising error please confirm

Comment: I guess this issue is not related to the code inside `save` method

Comment: i dont know but if i remove def create()   image will save and i can see it path in db... maybe def upload_to_custom_p is problem ????

Comment: It is not `create` method it must be `save` in your model, Do you have a minimal version of the code on Github?

Comment: in first line of error i have this :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deb/PycharmProjects/ac2/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Comment: Update the log into question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176508/discussion-between-satendra-and-finfin).