# Get name of image when uploading

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using this code to check the size of an image before uploading on the model. I would like to get the image name so I can communicate to the users what the offending file is. How would I go about this.

```
def validate_image(image):
    file_size = image.file.size
    if file_size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError("Max size of file is 3MB")

image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',validators=[validate_image])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django validate and convert any image to jpeg then save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462779/django-validate-and-convert-any-image-to-jpeg-then-save)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari image.name does not work

Comment: did you try image.file.name to access the filename?

Answer (score 0):

[FieldFile.name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name)

> The name of the file including the relative path from the root of the Storage of the associated FileField.

[Sample](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models):

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')

>>> car = Car.objects.get(name="57 Chevy")
>>> car.photo
<ImageFieldFile: cars/chevy.jpg>
>>> car.photo.name  # <-- this one !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
'cars/chevy.jpg'
>>> car.photo.path
'/media/cars/chevy.jpg'
>>> car.photo.url
'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'
```